# Cannot set function attribute inside a decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a Python code like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def dec(f): 
    
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        f.foo = 'foo'
        value = f()
        f.foo = 'foo'
        return value
    return wrapper

@dec
def f():
    print('Hello, f')

f()
print(f.foo)
```

You can find the ready code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/y1t0l7OFb):

The problem with this code is that I end up with `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'foo'`, although I use `wraps` decorator from functools which should preserve the attribute scope of the function. Any ideas what the cause of the error is ?

Comment: `dec` needs to return `wrapper` not `f`. Your decorator is a no-op at present.

Comment: The `foo` attribute is only created when you call `f()`. If you want it to be created at "decoration time", move that line into `dec`, not `wrapper`.

Comment: Fixed that, but it still doesn't eliminate the root issue

Comment: @deceze, see the updated code in the question. The issue still persists

Comment: That isn't what deceze suggested. You're calling f() twice for no reason

Comment: Can you please provide a working code so that I can get your idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the attribute on `f`, but you're returning `wrapper` and the `f` in the main scope is that `wrapper` function object. To illustrate with less confusing names:

```
def dec(f): 
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        f.foo = 'foo'  # <-- this is the original bar function
        value = f()
        return value

    return wrapper

@dec
def bar():
    print('Hello, f')

bar()  # <-- this is wrapper()
```

When you change your code to `wrapper.foo = 'foo'`, it works as expected.

Comment: Let me disagree with you, @deceze. This is actually what the `functool`'s `wraps` function does. See this code - https://onlinegdb.com/3UnBzZME65. Play around with it with and without wraps decorator

Comment: `wraps` makes sure the signature of `wrapper` *looks like* that of `f`. It doesn't make them the same object. The decorator syntax is sugar for `bar = dec(bar)`. `bar` will be whatever `dec` returns. `dec` returns `wrapper`. `bar` *is* `wrapper`. You're not setting the attribute on that object, so it doesn't show up there.